# How to use inspectdb for multiple mysql schemas in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

This is the DATABASES dictionary in my `Settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'account',
        'USER': 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

My database has multiple schemas, for example, account, login, notifications etc.
When I do a python manage.py inspectdb, I only get the classes for the tables in the "account" schema, but I want the classes for all the schemas.
I tried doing `python manage.py inspectdb --database=login`, but I get a `django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist` exception

But, if I change the settings to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'account',
        'USER': 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    },
    'login': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'login',
        'USER': 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    },
}
```

I get the proper classes of the table login on executing `python manage.py inspectdb --database=login`. But, problem is, if this is supposed to be the procedure, I have to make an option in the `DATABASES` option, which will become really long, as I have more than 15 schemas, and I am not sure if doing that will be a good thing or not.

So, I want to know what is the right way of doing this.

I am on Django 1.10.5.

Comment: Why do not you put all your tables in a single database?

Comment: @aumo I can't. It's a legacy database or a live application, and I cannot change anything in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Django needs to know how to reach each one of your databases so you won't be able to avoid declaring them in the `DATABASES` setting. If your only concern is that you will loose readability, you may create a helper function to get rid of repetition.

For example:

```
def local_db(name):
    return {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': name,
        'USER': 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }

DATABASES = {
    'default': local_db('account'),
    'login': local_db('login'),
    # Etc.
}
```

If you want to inspect all databases at once, you may create a custom command to do so.

For example:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management.commands.inspectdb import Command as BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        for db_name in settings.DATABASES:
            options['database'] = db_name
            self.stdout.write('# Generated while inspecting database %s\n' % db_name)
            super().handle(**options)
```

Comment: My main concern is that, when I do it this way, I am not able to get all the model classes for the tables in the `login` db. I only get the model classes of the tables of the `default` db on executing on `inspectdb`

Comment: Even when you specify the `--database` option?

Comment: if I specify the `--database`, Then only the specified database comes. So, is it that I have to specify it for all my databases?

Comment: Yes, you have to run the command for every database. You may create a custom command that will iterate over the databases and run `inspectdb` on each.

Comment: The reason I was hoping it could be done is because, there is only one `models.py` file in a django app (I am not sure if multiple model files is possible), and i do something like `python manage.py inspectdb --database=login > models.py`, the `models.py` will have the classes of the login db. Now, when I execute the command `python manage.py inspectdb --database=account > models.py`, for the second db, the contents of the `models.py` file is replaced with the classes of account db, and the login db classes are replaced.

Comment: You can use `>> models.py` to append to the models file instead of overwriting it. The custom command solution would also work.

Comment: Wow that worked, I have a few more questions regarding Database routing, that I will post in details, would be of great help if you can look into it, I will add the link once I post the question.